# Javascript code analysis: Count function, variable calls and usage in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, refactoring

Are there any tools that can count the number times a function or variable is called or passed in a javascript file?

I am looking to refactor code. Having this information would help me to break out the code.

Working this out can obviously done manually by searching, but I would preferably like to be able generate an accurate report automatically as I am working with large files.

Comment: have you found any?

Comment: I also have this problem, did you find one?

Answer (score 1):

[brackets](http://brackets.io) with [theseus](http://github.com/adobe-research/theseus) might be what you need.

It can count how many times a function is called in your code while debugging.

[image]

Comment: Cheers, but not quite what I'm looking. I'm looking to have an analysis of non running code